# Zero-inflated poisson/nb -- which covariates should I put in the inflation (logit) model and which should I put in the count model?

Tags: zero-inflation, controlling-for-a-variable

I'm using a zero inflated count model (either poisson or negative binomial). I have a set of control variables that I want to include in addition to the main independent variable of interest.

Can anyone offer any guidance as to how to choose which covariates to include in the inflation model, and which to include in the count model? Intuitively it just seems like for any covariate which I should expect to affect the zero/non-zero status of the outcome, I should also expect it to affect the count of the outcome conditional on it being non-zero (and vice versa).

Is it problematic to include all covariates in both stages?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, it's not a problem to include all variables in both parts of the model. Exceptions would be if there are some covariates with (quasi-)complete separation of the response in zero and non-zero counts. Then this would need to be addressed as in binary response models with separation.

Otherwise, if you have no prior knowledge about which variable drives which effects in the model, I would recommend to start with a model that includes all regressors in both parts.

Moreover, I would recommend to explore hurdle models (or two-part models) as an alternative to zero-inflated models. The effects are easier to interpret and both models can, in principle, be fitted separately. So it is easier to interpret coefficients and select variables etc.